# Add text annotation to plot from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, annotations

My Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os, glob

path = r'C:/Users/New folder'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file_ in all_files:
    file_df = pd.read_csv(file_,sep=',', parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True,header=None, usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6], names=['Date','Time','open', 'high', 'low', 'close','volume','tradingsymbol'])

df = df[['Date','Time','close','volume','tradingsymbol']]
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
print(df)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
################### Volume ###########################
df.groupby('tradingsymbol')['volume'].plot(legend=True, rot=0, grid=True, ax=axes[0])
################### PRICE ###########################
df.groupby('tradingsymbol')['close'].plot(legend=True, rot=0, grid=True, ax=axes[1])

plt.show()
```

My Current Output is like:
[image: Output]

I need add text annotation to matplotlib plot. My desired output similar to below image[image: Desired]:

Comment: At one point you will need to decide: Do you want to have working solutions to your questions? Then provide a [mcve]. If not, feel free to continue asking questions without runnable code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to answer this question without access to your dataset, or a simpler example. However, I'll try my best.

Let's begin by setting up a dataframe which may or may resemble your data:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 3)),
                    columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

With the dataset we'll now proceed to plot it with

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
df.plot(legend=True, ax=ax)
```

Finally, we'll loop over the columns and annotate each datapoint as

```py
for col in df.columns:
    for id, val in enumerate(df[col]):
        ax.text(id, val, str(val))
```

This gave me the plot following plot, which resembles your desired figure.
[image]

Comment: Sir, How to convert df.groupby('tradingsymbol')['volume'] data to x1 (I mean numpay array)

Comment: You can convert with the [pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) function. I.e. ```df.groupby('tradingsymbol')['volume'].to_numpy()```.

Comment: I'm not very confident with ```pandas```, but i suspect you can loop over the values as ```for i, x in enumerate(df.groupby('tradingsymbol')['volume'])```

Comment: Not Working. Something is missing. AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Please see my edit --- I've altered the example to plot from a pandas dataframe.